# complex batch replacement linux

Tags: regex, batch-file, replace

I'm trying to do some batch replacement for/with a fairly complex pattern

So far I find the pattern as:

```
find '(' -name '*.php' -o -name '*.html' ')' -exec grep -i -n 'hello' {} +
```

The string I want to replace is currently as follow:

```
<img src="/some/path/to/somewhere/hello" />
```

where the path for the image varies but always contain the sub-string 'hello' at the end

I would like to grab the path and perform a replacement as follow:

```
<img src="<?php myfunction('(/some/path/to/somewhere/)'); ?>" />
```

What would a good way to perform this?

Any help will be appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `-exec grep .....` with

```
-exec cat '{}' | sed s/<img src="(/some/path/to/somewhere/)hello" />/<img src="<?php myfunction('(\1)(constant)'); ?>" />/ > /tmp/output; mv /tmp/output '{}' ';'
```

escaping spaces, " and / symbols in sed's search and replacement patterns with backslahes as sed likes.

For instance, this will extract /path/:

```
echo "<img src=\"/path/hello\"" | sed "s/<img\ src=\"\(\/path\/\)hello/\1/"
```

Comment: that seems to be a good approach, the only thing is that as mentioned, the path changes from file to file. So I dont have a unique path. This can be /some/path/to/somewhere/ or /here/path/to/someother/ ...

Comment: Replace it with .* then, like echo "<img src=\"/longer/path/hello\"" | sed "s/<img\ src=\"\(\/.*\/\)hello/\1/"

Comment: and add /g at the end of sed in this case, I guess